# Is there an adjective to describe a location in which there usually is heavy traffic?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, translation

In Portuguese we say a place is very "congestionado", that is, traffic is usually backed up. So, is there a way to describe a neighborhood, or city to mean that it usually has backed up traffic?
For example

> "Chicago is ____"

Comment: ***Congested:*** roads and towns have too much traffic and movement is made difficult. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/congested

Comment: @JOSH's answer is clearly correct, but why was a simple Google Translate not good enough? This question can be answered using general references.

Comment: There's the usual **trouble spots** on the Ike today and there's a crash blocking both right lanes on the inbound just before the Circle. Now, here's Tom with the weather...

Comment: A particular intersection can be described being “***busy***” If you’re just learning to drive I’d avoid Main and Fifth, that’s a busy intersection.

Answer (score 1):

"Congested" is the best suited answer..

Comment: Thank you for answering this question, but it may be better to have posted this as a community wiki question as J O S H in the comments has already got it. Nonetheless, you also need to back up your answer using references and explain why it fits. See [answer].